# Grouping Unix Timestamp by Day Producing Unevenly Spaced Groups

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, group-by, timestamp

I'm using a MySQL query to pull a range of datetimes as a Unix Timestamp (because I'll be converting them to Javascript time).  I'm grouping by 'FROM_UNIXTIME' as below:

```
SELECT 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DateAndTime) as x, 
    Sum(If(Pass='Pass',1,0)) AS y, 
    Sum(If(Pass='Fail',1,0)) AS z, 
    Sum(If(Pass='Fail',1,0))/(Sum(If(Pass='Pass',1,0))+Sum(If(Pass='Fail',1,0))) AS a,
    cases.primaryApp 
FROM casehistory, cases
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 80 DAY) <= DateAndTime
AND cases.caseNumber = casehistory.caseNumber
AND cases.primaryApp = 'Promo'
GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(x, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

While I'd expected my timestamps to be returnd evenly spaced (that is, same amount of time between each day/group), I get the following series:

> 1300488140, 1300501520,
>   1300625099, 1300699980

All the other data from the query is correct, but because the spacing of the timestamps is irregular, a bar chart based on these stamps looks pretty awful.  Perhaps I'm doing something wrong in the way I apply the grouping?

---

Thank you for the reply.  My query 'made sense' in that it produced that could be plotted (the grouping was done on the x alias for the dateandtime value), but the problem was that pulling a Unix timestamp from the database and grouping by day returned a series of timestamps that did not have equal distance between them.

I solved this by pulling only the day (without the time) from the datetime MySQL field, then -  in PHP - concatenating an empty time to the date, converting the resulting string to a time, then multiplying the whole shebang by 1000 to return the Javascript time I needed for the charting, like this:

```
x = x . ' 00:00:00';
x = strtotime(x) * 1000;
```

The answer put me on the right track; I'll accept it.  My chart looks perfect now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is very confused.

Your SQL statement makes no sense - you are grouping by entities not found in the select statement. And a bar chart plots an ordered set of values - so if there's something funny with the spacing then its not really a bar chart.

But I think the answer you are looking for is:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateandtime, '%Y-%m-%d') as ondate
, SUM(IF(Pass='Pass',1,0)) AS passed
, SUM(IF(Pass='Fail',1,0)) AS failed
, SUM(IF(Pass='Fail',1,0))
  /(SUM(IF(pass='Pass',1,0))+SUM(IF(Pass='Fail',1,0))) AS fail_pct
, cases.primaryapp 
FROM casehistory, cases
WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 80 DAY) <= dateandtime
AND cases.casenumber = casehistory.casenumber
AND cases.primaryapp = 'Promo'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(dateandtime, '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY 1;
```

And if you need Unix timestamps, wrap the above in....

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(ilv.ondate, ' 00:00:00'))) AS tstamp
, passed
, failed
, fail_pct
, primaryapp
FROM (
     ...
) AS ilv
```

Note that you'll still get anomolies around DST switches.

C.